# when i vagrant up, port 80 is not forwarded

Tags: vagrant

i get this output when i vagrant up, port 80 is not forwarding so how i will be able to access the site via web browser

```
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> default: Importing base box 'hashicorp/precise64'...
==> default: Matching MAC address for NAT networking...
==> default: Checking if box 'hashicorp/precise64' is up to date...
==> default: Setting the name of the VM: Homestead_default_1472822347316_22641
==> default: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
==> default: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
    default: Adapter 1: nat
==> default: Forwarding ports...
    default: 22 (guest) => 2222 (host) (adapter 1)
==> default: Booting VM...
==> default: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
    default: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2222
    default: SSH username: vagrant
    default: SSH auth method: private key
    default:
    default: Vagrant insecure key detected. Vagrant will automatically replace
    default: this with a newly generated keypair for better security.
    default:
    default: Inserting generated public key within guest...
    default: Removing insecure key from the guest if it's present...
    default: Key inserted! Disconnecting and reconnecting using new SSH key...
==> default: Machine booted and ready!
```

help me ,thanks

Comment: Did you add a port forwarding statement to your Vagrantfile?

Comment: how can i add that statement @mwp

Comment: @mwp now i have vagrant up again and port 80 is forwarded but when i access site on browser it says **this site cant be reached** and i have added it in my hosts file

Comment: Try http://localhost:8080

Comment: @mwp nope still not working

Comment: Then you might have a problem with the web server running on your guest not responding to (forwarded) requests.

Comment: @mwp Okay, btw 8080 was busy so i did 8888 i guess that is not the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default Vagrantfile, generated by `vagrant init`, includes an example of how to forward port 80:

```
# config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: 8080
```

Simply uncomment this line and adjust the ports as necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Vagrant can't forward host ports < 1024.

So if you do `config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: 80` it won't work.

You can use a local SSH tunnel to listen on port 80 on your host and forward the traffic to port 80 on your guest.

`sudo ssh -p 2222 -gNfL 80:localhost:80 vagrant@localhost -i ~/.vagrant.d/insecure_private_key`